# Is it possible to relaunch an activity from another activity after the finish() method has been called on it?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-finish

Is it possible to relaunch an activity **A** from activity **B** after the **finish()** method has been called from activity **A**?

how can I go about it in order to achieve this?

Comment: To go from activity B to A _startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class));_

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activityb.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Use this piece of code and just change the activity name accordingly. This will finish your acitivty A and redirect to activity B